# Very small JonTron quoter

Tags: c++, beginner

This is one of my first projects, just a quick hobby thing for fun.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using std::chrono::system_clock;

int random();

int main()
{
    cout << "Choose a JonTron episode!" << endl;
    string JonTron;
    getline(cin,JonTron);
    cout << "You chose " << JonTron << "." << endl;
    if (JonTron == "Aquaman")
        cout << "What's this blue pants? What-- what's this blue pants?" << endl;
else if (JonTron == "Anti-Drug Games")
    cout << "Too late, talking leg!" << endl;
else if (JonTron == "Banjo-Kazooie")
    cout << "CAAAAAAAAAAAAARS??? CARS?!?!?!" << endl;
else if (JonTron == "California Games")
    {cout << "SWOOD THIS! SWOOD THAT! What the FUCK does SWOOD mean?!?!?!" << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "I used to say it all the time in Cali! Grommet this, grommet that!";
    }
else if (JonTron == "Nightshade")
    {
    cout << "Congratulations! You've just won the Jef and Paul Award for Excellence in Shopping Centers!"<< endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
    cout << "Actually, the crowbar snaps in two." << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
    cout << "Just kidding." << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(5000));
    cout << "Fool me once, I'm mad." << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(5000));
    cout << "Fool me twice, how could you?" << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(5000));
    cout << "Fool me three times, you're officially that guy, okay--" << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
    cout << "You know the one, you go to a bar, and he's like," << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
    cout << "'This suit is ehh, official, it's a Giorgio Armani, actually, my dad knows him'," << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
    cout << "FUCK YOU!" << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "I AIIIIIIIIIN'T HAVIN' THAT SHIT!!" << endl;
    }
else if (JonTron == "The Skateboard Kid")
    cout << "You just wanna hang up somebody's coat, and the couch falls out!" << endl;
else if (JonTron == "The Zoo Race")
    cout << "What'd they program this in, C--??" << endl;
    else
        cout << "What the fuuuuuck?" << endl;
cout << "You done now? We done? (Press any key [and then hit enter, duy] to be done.)" << endl;
float fuckingdummyvar;
cin >> fuckingdummyvar;
}
```

My current main concern is the very large block of `if`-`elseif`-`else`. To put things concisely, is there any less gigantically ugly way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

You could use a switch statement instead of the if elses to make it prettier.

Or, you could use a `map<string, vector<string>>`

1. **Instead of using whole namespaces, restrict usage to single items.**

   In order to not pollute your own namespace with names, do single 'using' instead of 'using namespace'. The following will suffice for your code.

   ```
   using namespace std;
   using chrono::milliseconds;
   using chrono::system_clock;
   using this_thread::sleep_for;
   ```
2. Instead of `float fuckingdummyvar; cin >> fuckingdummyvar;`, do a single `getchar()` or [use any other method described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)
3. **Use consistent bracing.**

   This is a matter of opinion, but I prefer to always have braces around if and else statements, even when only one statement follows. I used to not put any braces, but then I ran into a nice bug that was seriously puzzling me when I added a return to an `else` and it would always return for some reason. That's because the return was the second statement after the else and there weren't brackets around it.
4. **Use a map to avoid big 'n' dirty blocks of code.**.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <chrono>
   #include <thread>
   #include <map>
   #include <vector>

   using namespace std;
   using chrono::milliseconds;
   using chrono::system_clock;
   using this_thread::sleep_for;


   int main()
   {
       map<string, vector<string>> quotes{
                                           {"Aquaman", {"What's this blue pants? What-- what's this blue pants?"}},
                                           {"California Games", { "SWOOD THIS! SWOOD THAT! What the FUCK does SWOOD mean?!?!?!", "I used to say it all the time in Cali! Grommet this, grommet that!" }},
                                           {"The Zoo Race", {"What'd they program this in, C--??"}}
                                         }; //In C++11 and up {"String1", "String2"} is a vector<string> = {"String1", "String2"}

       cout << "Choose a JonTron episode!" << endl;
       string JonTron;
       getline(cin, JonTron);

       if (quotes.count(JonTron)) { //Checks if there is a map key with the episode that the user inputted.
           for (auto &s : quotes[JonTron]) { //Iterates over every string in the vector<string> that's stored in quotes[JonTron].
               cout << s << endl;
               sleep_for(milliseconds(1000)); //If you want custom sleep times as well, do a map<string, customClass with vector of quotes and vector of milliseconds.
           }
       }
       else {
           cout << "Episode not found!.";
       }

       getchar();
   }
   ```
5. **Use a text file with all the quotes and episodes.**

   The best way would be to create a text file and retrieve the quotes from there.

Comment: A csv-file might be a good idea since you can open it in excel or similar programs